# how to manage multiple activity preferably

Tags: java, android, android-activity

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  ArrayList<Activity> mActivityList = new ArrayList<Activity>();

  public void addActivity(Activity a){

     mActivityList.add(a);
   } 

   public void removeActivity(Activity a){
      for(...){
         ...name equals..
         a.finish();
      }

   }

    public void removeAll(){
       for(){
        ...
        a.finish();
        }
   }

    public Activity getActivity(){...};

}
```

It is a very easy way to manage the activities, but the heap memory of the mActivityList cost much.  so is there another way to manage the activities

Comment: Tell us why you want to keep this list?

Comment: for example,i want to click one button then close all activities,or sometimes i want to close all activities except HomeActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking activities in a list is definitely not a good way.

If your only intention of doing so is to finish all (or any) of them conveniently, I suggest you take a look into BroadcastReceiver

Here's a snippet you can include into all your activities:

```
private BroadcastReceiver finishBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Start listening to any broadcast "tagged" with action name actionFinish.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(finishBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("actionFinish"));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop listening to broadcast when the activity is destroyed.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(finishBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

And do this whenever you want to finish all the activities:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent("actionFinish"));
```

Manipulate the Intent object by using Intent.putExtra() to identify which Activity you wish to dispose, if not all.

Comment: thanks ,it works perfectly!Broastreceiver is an easy way to close the activities. But i still don't know how to "getActivity()"

Comment: Is there any reason why you would want to get a reference of activity? to perform some functions? if yes, I would also suggest you to use broadcastreceiver to do it, just modify the `finish()` to do what you want..

Comment: yes i got a reason, in my project,i start a service keep accessing the data server every 15 mins,if it got new message then it show a notification at the title bar. then i click the notification so that it start an activity  called "MsgActivity" .now the point is, if the old "MsgActivity" exist,i should close it and start a new one. If you read the PendingIntent.getActivity(...),you would realize the activity will start with "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" flag. this is why i want to get the reference of activity